# FogBugz not appearing on my 'accounts' tab

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I've recently joined the FogBugz stack exchange using my OpenID and the account isn't appearing in my list of different accounts:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/370103?tab=accounts

Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FogBugz site is a Stack Exchange 1.0 site. Those sites were run independently from SOFU; they're owned by individuals, and not part of the network, so you can't associate accounts between them. Sites launched through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (Stack Exchange 2.0 sites) stay under the control of Stack Overflow Internet Services, and are all interconnected

<sub>([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StackExchange#StackExchange_1.0) about the difference)</sub>

Comment: So this means if I use 'fogbugz.stackexchange.com' I cannot use my StackExchange account? I was wondering why it wasn't giving me the option for this.